# Facebook Login For Android

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

I'm developing an android application with facebook authentication (login with facebook feature). I've integrated facebook SDK successfully, But when i press login with facebook button, below dialog appears. So look and feel is more facebooky, Instead i need just a single native dialog behavior like 2nd dialog below...

[image]

But what i need is to show below dialog:

[image]

Please suggest me how to get above dialog instead of the first facebook login dialog.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have deprecated that second dialog that you show.  Now the only 2 options are to do an app transition to the Facebook app on the device or to show a WebView which will have a similar look and feel.  Is it the look that you want or the different permissions?  If look, we are moving away from that because we want users to feel more comfortable about what they are sharing and see it more clearly.  If permissions, you can add those to your request.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Yes it is the look and feel I needed. I wasn't aware that the 2nd dialog is deprecated. I'll go ahead with first dialog. Yes its good with new dialog user can decide what information to share. Thanks for all information provided.